# How to create an XML string and pass it to a stored procedure on MS SQL server using MS Access VBA?

Tags: ms-access, vba

How can I create an XML string and pass it to a stored procedure on MS SQL server using MS Access Visual Basic for Applications (VBA) ?

Answer (score 0):

From the article below it seems that the way to do this is to pass it as a VarChar and let the SQL server parse it server side

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa224791(SQL.80).aspx

*“You can then pass an entire XML hierarchy into a stored procedure as a varchar or text parameter and parse the hierarchy inside SQL Server to add, update, and delete multiple records in multiple tables within one stored procedure call”*